# I need to remove JSON or markdown files from vinyl stream using gulp based on property in file

Tags: gulp

I have markdown files in a structure like the following:

```
---
title: some title
tags: [misc]
date: '2015-09-09'
---

some text
```

I have a gulp task like the following

```
gulp.task('hits', function(){
    var index = 0;
  gulp.src('source/content/agents/*.md')
   //.pipe(changed())
    .pipe(markdown({
        pedantic: true,
        smartypants: true
    }))
    .pipe( buffer() )
    .pipe(jeditor(function(json) {
     return json; // must return JSON object. 
  }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('server/content/hits'));
});
```

in the case that the input file does not have a value hit in the tags array I want to remove it from the stream. This can be done either before or after the json step, I guess before would be best, but either is fine.

I'm pretty sure this must be a simple thing to do given that you know the right plugin and how to use that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here at the beginning of your markdown file isn't JSON at all. A proper JSON document would look like this:

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "tags": ["misc"],
  "date": "2015-09-09"
}
```

What you're dealing with here is [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). More specifically this type of YAML data, which acts as metadata at the beginning of a markdown document, is called [Front Matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) and was popularized by the [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) static site generator.

There's a gulp plugin called [`gulp-front-matter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-front-matter) that is specifically designed to deal with this kind of metadata. It parses the front matter and attaches the resulting values to the vinyl file.

This in combination with the [`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) plugin allows you to filter out files from the stream based on the tags that are present in the front matter:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var frontMatter = require('gulp-front-matter');
var markdown = require('gulp-markdown');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('hits', function () {
  return gulp.src('source/content/agents/*.md')
    .pipe(frontMatter())
    .pipe(markdown())
    .pipe(filter(function(file) {
      return file.frontMatter.tags &&
             file.frontMatter.tags.indexOf('hit') >= 0;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('server/content/hits'))
});
```

Comment: I didn't say it was json, I said I have markdown files with that structure, I turn them into json. after the markdown step so I was expecting to filter them either at the markdown or json steps but thanks I will try gulp-filter.